# PHP-Loop through html table and get label text

Tags: php, parsing, domdocument

I have an HTML Table and its each rows are identified with an unique id. I'm trying to get the label text inside one of row. I tried with `$dom->getElementById($id);` but this provides all text values coming under that element.

Here is the structure:

```
<table>
<tr id="1">.....</tr>
<tr id="2">
<td>
<span>Some text</span>
</td>
<td>
.
.  //Some html elements
.
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<label>label1</label>
</td>                         //I want to collect these labels
<td>
<label>label2</label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</tabel>
.
.
.
```

I tried with this `$elements = $dom->getElementById('2');` code. It provides all values together.

Output

```
 ["nodeValue"]=> string(37) "Select your options *option 1option 2"
```

How can I get only label text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `getElementsByTagName`? E.g. :

```
$elements = $dom->getElementById('2')->getElementsByTagName('label');
```

(edited):

then you'll be able to access the items:

```
for($i=0;$i<$elements->length;$i++) {
       echo "Item $i: " . $elements->item($i)->textContent . "\n";
}
```

Comment: It returns only length. `object(DOMNodeList)#416 (1) { ["length"]=> int(2) }`

Comment: then, it seems you should be able to access item(x). I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Perfect. I didn't thought it is possible to access the elements in this way. thanks for help...